# Take multiple inputs from text files in java

Tags: java, input, file-io

I write a program and need to generate results for different input (integer) values. which i have to read some integer numbers from several text files and store them in these variables.

- choice
- numofNodes
- numofPoints

in each file there might be multiple numbers that should be assigned to one of above variables, for example:

First text file contains five values for first variables and other two variables have one value on separate lines like below:

```
1 2 3 4 5
60
50
```

Second text file contains five values for second variables and other two variables have one value on separate lines like below:

```
1 
40 50 60 70 80
50
```

and so on..

I have no idea how to read them from text files.
any helps will be appreciated.

Here's my Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws InterruptedException {

    // how to read numbers from different text files here
    // and store them in these variables to call func method?
    // int choice = ? 
    // int numofNode = ?
    // int numofPoint = ?

    path ob=new path(choice,numofNode,numofPoint);
    ob.func();

}
```

Comment: Read [read](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/) and [write](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/)

Comment: @TheLostMind, edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put files path in a string array. then you can read the files by creating an instance of `java.util.Scanner` class that has several methods to read file content.

all you need is to use for and for-each loops to loop through your files and read them.

here's some code that i hope helps!

```
/**
 * converts array of string numbers to array of integer numbers.
 *
 * @param numbers is array of strings
 * @return an integer array which is parsed from <b>numbers</b>
 *
 */
static int[] parseInt(String[] numbers) {
    return Arrays.stream(numbers).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // put input files path here
    String[] name_and_path_of_files = {
        "C:\\Users\\YOUR_USER\\Desktop\\input_1.txt",
        "C:\\Users\\YOUR_USER\\Desktop\\input_2.txt"
    };

    // file reader
    Scanner inputFileReader = null;
    try {

        // for all files
        for (String fileInfo : name_and_path_of_files) {

            // create reader object with file info
            inputFileReader = new Scanner(new File(fileInfo));

            int line_index = 0;

            int choices[] = null;
            int numofNodes[] = null;
            int numofPoints[] = null;

            // trying to read file content
            while (inputFileReader.hasNext()) {
                String separated_numbers[] = inputFileReader.nextLine().split(" ");
                switch (line_index) {
                    case 0:
                        choices = parseInt(separated_numbers);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        numofNodes = parseInt(separated_numbers);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        numofPoints = parseInt(separated_numbers);
                        break;
                }
                line_index++;
            }

            for (int choice : choices) {
                for (int numofPoint : numofPoints) {
                    for (int numofNode : numofNodes) {
                        path ob = new path(choice, numofNode, numofPoint);
                        ob.func();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (inputFileReader != null) {
            inputFileReader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tina check my answer.